# How many memory locations will it take?

Tags: java

I just want to know, In java how many memory locations will it take to assing to string variables with same value.

For Example :

```
String name1 = "Test";
String name2 = "Test";
```

Will this take 2 memory locations or only 1 since the values are equal in JAVA. Thanks

Comment: I think only one location :)

Comment: Only one location.I am sharing with you a very good link which proves it in better way::  http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html

Comment: Thanks for all your answers...You people made this concept so clear..Accepting the first answer and giving you all up votes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String` literals are stored in a common pool.

This facilitates sharing of storage for strings with the same contents to conserve storage.

So one location for both.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [String-intern'ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), all the compile time constants will go into the *String intern pool* and thus, only 1 `"Test"` would be created in the pool which will take up only 1 memory location.

And both `name1` and `name2` will be assigned with the same reference from the pool.

Answer (score 1):

This will occupy only one memory location.

```
String name1 = "Test";
String name2 = "Test";
```

The reason is that both `name1` and `name2` refer to the same String in the inter pool.

If you had something like:

```
String name1 = "Test";
String name2 = new String("Test");
```

then, two different object would be created.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. C is a different language which may work internally in a different way.

Comment: @uma_SF I suppose, no in c it would take 2 memory locations.

Answer (score 1):

only one because once you declare variable `name` and assign value as "Test" after that if same value you are assigning to different variable it will still point to same unless and until you explicitly create new object of string with same value.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one memory location there and both `name1` and `name2` will refer that location.

If you do following way, There are two memory location for `name1` and `name2`

```
    String name1 = new String("Test");
    String name2 = new String("Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is an article about the String usage in JVM : [Memory usage of Java Strings and string-related objects](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml)

### How to calculate String memory usage

For reasons we'll explore below, the minimum memory usage of a Java String (in the Hotspot Java 6 VM) is generally as follows:

```
Minimum String memory usage (bytes) = 8 * (int) ((((no chars) * 2) + 45) / 8)
```

Or, put another way:

- multiply the number of characters of the String by two;
- add 38;
- if the result is not a multiple of 8,
- round up to the next multiple of 8;
- the result is generally the minimum number of bytes taken up on the heap by the String.

---

- if the string is in PermGen, thow String will occupy only one space.
- if not, two String will occupy twice space.
- besides, `String.subString()` will return a new string, but the two strings share the inner char array.